# how to select singel and multiple checkbox with radiobutton

Tags: javascript, html

i'm stuck with this problem. i have 2 radiobutton and few checkbox. what i want to do is if radiobutton1 chacked, it only allow check 1 checkbox, then if radiobutton2 chacked, it will allow all checkbox to be checked.

i've been tried some script, but not any of them work.

this is my code for sample.

**HTML**

```
<input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radiobtn1" />
<input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radiobtn2" />

<input type="checkbox" name="cb" value="1" onclick="test(this)" />
<input type="checkbox" name="cb" value="2" onclick="test(this)"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="cb" value="3" onclick="test(this)"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="cb" value="4" onclick="test(this)"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="cb" value="5" onclick="test(this)"/>
```

---

**script for select only 1 checkbox**

```
function test(id){
    var cb = document.getElementsByName("cb");
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(cb,function(el){
      el.checked = false;
     });
        id.checked = true;
     }
```

---

**my script**

```
$(function test(id){
$("#radio1, #radio2").change(function(){
    if($("#radio1").is(":checked")){
      var cb = document.getElementsByName("cb");
      Array.prototype.forEach.call(cb,function(el){
        el.checked = false;
      });
      id.checked = true;
    }
    else if($("#radio2").is(":checked")){

    }
});
});
```

thank you for your help.

Comment: change **$(function test(id){** to **$(function () {** and remove **id.checked = true;** because useless

Comment: i've tried it but still i can select all checkbox .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's like your question has been solved.
next time try to find it first.

but you can try this script.

```
var $form = $('#form1');
var $checkboxes = $('input[type=checkbox]');
var $selectionType = $('input[type=radio]');
var $output = $('#output');

// Used to determine if the Multi radio is selected
var isMulti = false;

// Listen to change event on the radio buttons and set isMulti
$selectionType.on('change', function( e ) {
// Check the value of what radio button was clicked
isMulti = $( e.target ).val() === 'Multi';

// Clear all selected checkboxes if user clicked "single"
if( !isMulti ) {
    $checkboxes.each( function( idx, item ) {
        $( item ).prop( 'checked', false );
    });
}
});

// Listen to clicks on checkboxes
$checkboxes.on('change', function( e ) {

// Store what was just clicked
var $this = $( e.target );

// If Multi is not selected, then remove the check from all checkboxes except
// the one that the user actually clicked on
if( !isMulti ) {

    $checkboxes.each( function( idx, item ) {

        var $item = $( item );

        if( $item.attr('id') === $this.attr('id') ) {
            return true;
        }

        $item.prop('checked', false );
    });
}
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/grammar/pdx8gccu/2/